# "HighCharts not showing in IE, works well with mozilla, chrome"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have also included the required JavaScript library highcharts.js. worked a lot on it but no responses. Can anyone help?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  "highcharts" %>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. This question in it's current form is unanswerable. I'm voting to close it unless it's fleshed out a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include this in your page

```
< !--[if IE]>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'excanvas.compiled.js' %>
< ![endif]-->
```